# Light-weight Library for Image Editing in C# and .NET

Tags: .net, image-processing

I am looking for an online image processing library which is:

- Light weight and fast
- Easy to integrate with .NET C# web app
- Easy to configure and customize (if I don't want all features?)
- Open source or free or cheap

I will use it for commercial purpose.

Is there anything similar that suits my needs better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Aforge.  it provides a whole heap of functionality and is open sourced.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/license.html